# How to Sort Nested Dictionaries .net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dictionary, nested

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Dictionary
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,float>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, float>>();
        String input = Console.ReadLine();
        String[] data = input.Split();
        string name = "";
        float result = 0;

        while (data[0] != "end")
        {
            if (data.Length == 1)
            {
                name = data[0];
                dict.Add(name, new Dictionary<string, float>());
            }
            else if (data.Length > 1)
            {
                result = float.Parse(data[1]);
                dict[name].Add(data[0], result);
            }

            data = Console.ReadLine().Split(); // input 
        }

        // var dic2 = from x in dict
        // orderby x.Key
        // select x; 

        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Country: {0}", item.Key);
            string temp = item.Key;

            foreach (var element in dict[temp])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("City: {0}, population: {1}", element.Key, element.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a Dictionary Key->country,nested->Dictionary Key->city,Value->population  where I want to
        sort country and population in the inner "nested" dictionary. I 
        spent few hours in search for the right answer but couldn't find the 
        solution to my problem. I am able to foreach the information but can't find the way to sort it. Any help appreciated.
        PS: I am just learning Dictionaries now.
        Thanks.

Comment: Could you make an example of how you expect the resulting sorted dictionary to be structured ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) for your inner dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have something like (numbers made up)

```
USA
- LA : 5000000
- New York : 10000000
- Boston : 3000000
Australia
- Sydney : 4000000
- Canberra : 500000
Canada
- Ontario : 1000000
- Toronto : 2000000
```

and you want it to be

```
Australia
- Canberra : 500000
- Sydney : 4000000
Canada
- Ontario : 1000000
- Toronto : 2000000
USA
- Boston : 3000000
- LA : 5000000
- New York : 10000000
```

First off, you can't sort a dictionary. But you do have some options.
[You can use a `SortedDictionary` where you specify the comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).
Or you can output the elements to a list of `KeyValuePairs` and sort that.

Comment: Yes I want to do exactly what you have in the example above. If it was one dictionary with Key and Value I could sort it with linq, I mean sort the elements to another KeyValuePair collection // var dic2 = from x in dict
        // orderby x.Key
        // select x;                but with nested Dictionary It didn work.

Comment: Well, as I said, you have two options:

Comment: if you want the elements always sorted, you can change `dict` to be a `SortedDictionary<string,SortedDictionary<string,float>>`.

or if you just want the elements outputted sorted at a given time, you could do something like 
`var sorted = dict.ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.Key).Select(country => new KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,float>>>(country.Key, country.Value.ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.Value))`

that code is off the top of my head, so prob has errors, but you get the idea